# ReactJS - Why does the form element return null?

Tags: reactjs, getelementbyid

I am using ReactJS to make a Login/Signup modal in which there is a signin and a signup form that users can switch between. When a user clicks on the "Sign in" tab, the "signup" form is moved out of the view, and the "signin" form is moved into the view. However, I got the error saying that `document.getElementById("signup")` returned a `null` (the "signin" form and "btn" have the same problem). Also, the console said that "`16 stack frames were collapsed`" at line 55. I attach the screenshots of the JS file, CSS file, and the localhost error page. Thanks for your patience.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

[image: Screenshot 4]

[image: Screenshot 5]

Comment: Add code directly to this post and not in images. Thanks

Comment: I added the screenshots inline. However, you should post the code as text.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the right thing in `signUp()` and `signIn()`, you probably want to change
`signUp() {}` to `signUp = () => {}` also `signIn() {}` to `signIn = () => {}`

then

`<Button onClick={this.signUp} />` instead of `<Button onClick={this.signUp()} />` also `<Button onClick={this.signIn} />` instead of `<Button onClick={this.signIn()} />`

---

With reference to your new code, I guess you are not supposed to use `document.getElementById` in constructor because the stuff you are calling might not exist in DOM yet, you may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

If you are not going to animate your view, but just purely changing their left position with absolute position, I suggest you to put the styles that you want to manipulate in the state.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = { 
    signupLeftPosition: 0, // put initial position here, now I assume it is 0
    signinLeftPosition: 0, // put initial position here, now I assume it is 0
    buttonLeftPosition: 0, // put initial position here, now I assume it is 0
  };
}
```

And your signUp()

```
signUp = () => {
  this.setState({ 
    signupLeftPosition: 50, 
    signinLeftPosition: 450, 
    buttonLeftPosition: 0
 })
}
```

And your forms, I'll take the form with the id "signup" as an example:

```
<form 
  class="input-group' 
  id="signup" 
  style={{ left: this.state.signupLeftPosition }} 
/>
```

Also do the same to your component with the id `signin` and `button`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It complied after I made the changes, but when I clicked the "Sign up" or "Sign in" tab, the console reported the same error.

Comment: What is `this.signup`? how do you define it?

Comment: My bad just realized that I did not upload the first part of the code... I define this.signup=document.getElementById("signup").

Comment: More complete code:
class Header extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state={
            showModal: false
        };

        this.openModal...
        this.closeModal...
        this.signup = document.getElementById("signup");
        this.signin = document.getElementById("signin");
        this.btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    }

    signIn = () => {
        this.signup.style.left = "-400px";
        this.signin.style.left = "50px";
        this.btn.style.left = "110px";
    }

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question and add the code back with it being wrapped with a code block in the first place, please have a look at this https://help.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks